# Deploy Cordova App to Tablet

Tags: android, cordova

I create a simple app with apache cordova, which I deploy on my local android emulator. Now, everything works fine, but I don't know how to deploy the app to my tablet. Any help?

Comment: Connect your tablet to your computer, make sure it is unlocked (not on the lock screen), also make sure that the developer mode is turned on and `USB debugging` is enabled, and then run `cordova run android`

Comment: unfortunately, this is just launching my local android emulator

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sometimes happens to me.

In addition to making sure you have developer mode and USB debugging enabled on your device, as Dawson Loudon suggested, I have to sometimes do the following:

I make sure my device is awake, and then unplug/replug in the USB connector, which prompts a "Allow USB debugging" dialog box on the device.

After I select OK, I can deploy to the device.

(If my device is asleep when I plug in the USB, I do not see this dialog and get the same behavior you described).